# Maven: 'mvn package' taking 30 seconds for one file change?

Tags: java, maven

Apologies if this is an obvious issue but my primary background isn't Java and it seems like I am doing something wrong. When I make changes to my source code I run `mvn package` to update this and produce a .jar.

Currently this command takes an average of 25 seconds each time, the device compiling it has 8 cores with 16 GB of RAM, so I can't see it being the performance of the machine.

What can I change to speed up my build times?

I've tried using multiple threads with `mvn package`, it doesn't seem to make any difference.

Here is the output log

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING]
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.eu.habbo:Habbo:jar:2.4.0
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.(groupId:artifactId:type:classifier)' must be unique: com.google.code.gson:gson:jar -> duplicate declaration of version 2.8.6 @ line 173, column 21
[WARNING]
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING]
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING]
[INFO]
[INFO] -------------------------< com.eu.habbo:Habbo >-------------------------
[INFO] Building Habbo 2.4.0
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ Habbo ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) @ Habbo ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 1799 source files to C:\Users\ash\Documents\roleplay-emulator\target\classes
[WARNING] /C:/Users/ash/Documents/roleplay-emulator/src/main/java/com/eu/habbo/Emulator.java:[22,52] com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.operations.Bool is internal proprietary API and may be removed in a future release
[INFO] /C:/Users/ash/Documents/roleplay-emulator/src/main/java/com/eu/habbo/habbohotel/rooms/Room.java: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
[INFO] /C:/Users/ash/Documents/roleplay-emulator/src/main/java/com/eu/habbo/habbohotel/rooms/Room.java: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
[INFO] /C:/Users/ash/Documents/roleplay-emulator/src/main/java/com/eu/habbo/networking/rconserver/RCONServer.java: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
[INFO] /C:/Users/ash/Documents/roleplay-emulator/src/main/java/com/eu/habbo/networking/rconserver/RCONServer.java: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ Habbo ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\ash\Documents\roleplay-emulator\src\test\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ Habbo ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ Habbo ---
[INFO] No tests to run.
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) @ Habbo ---
[INFO] Building jar: C:\Users\ash\Documents\roleplay-emulator\target\Habbo-2.4.0.jar
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-assembly-plugin:3.3.0:single (make-assembly) @ Habbo ---
[INFO] Building jar: C:\Users\ash\Documents\roleplay-emulator\target\Habbo-2.4.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  29.837 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-10-26T06:15:39Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

C:\Users\ash\Documents\roleplay-emulator>
```

The bottleneck seems to be in these lines here,

```
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 1799 source files to C:\Users\ash\Documents\roleplay-emulator\target\classes
```

Comment: If you can see it is compiling 1799 sources and creating a .jar package. So it doesn't make any difference if you change one or a hundred files. It would take same time when you compile all the sources.

Comment: The first problem I see that you have 1799 files within a single module. I have my doubts that all those classes belong to the same module. From my point of view often this shows a wrong design. separate different parts into different module with a less classes. Then parallelizing could help here. Furthermore I don't see any test there and also I usually use the IDE to work with code (fixes/ compile issues etc. ...jar files are usually only build on a CI server. I bet there are several package which could be separated into separate module which could improve the build time...

Comment: Run the same in debug mode (-X) and try to find out why it’s recompiling all the classes

Answer (score -1):

This is a normal amount of time.

I does not bother me a lot because why I work, Eclipse compiles the files in the background and I can see compile errors immediately. Also running JUnit tests through Eclipse works fine.

I only run Maven when I need the complete artifact.